# what can be done with the following data?

Tags: data-mining

I have scraped the rating that a customer gave in the following categories namely overall rating score, value for money, seat comfort,staff service, catering and entertainment from an airline forum. I would like to know what quality information I can deduce from such ratings about an airline. I have rating of nearly 300 customers who traveled in an airline.

Comment: 300 might potentially be a small sample in this context, how were the passengers distributed? Were they all on the same plane, on the same route ? Did they fly in the same week/month? Without sight of the data it's hard to say exactly what you might be able to extract from it. Maybe you could make your question more specific?

Comment: Sir, this is the website i scraped [ http://www.airlinequality.com/Forum/af.htm ]  Have a look at it. :)

Comment: is it possible to do something ? @image_doctor

Comment: Something needs definition, what type of question are you seeking to answer ?   Unless you want to analyse the textual comments of the reviewers, you only have a handful of unspecific features which tell you how a selection of passengers perceive the airline in some very general categories. You might be able to extract the country of origin of the reviewer and see how that affects perception.  Without other data you can't compare this airline to the performance of any other airline. Apart from distributions of scores for things like value for money, etc. what are you searching for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at it the wrong way. First, you need to have a question and then you may find out whether the data could potentially hold the answer to that question. Right now, you're asking us to what questions this data may hold the answer. And that is a very difficult question!

But to provide you with at least some ideas:

- Find out what people deem important (the correlation between overall rating and the other ratings in (linear) regression analyses)
- Find out the relation between certain characteristics of people (age/gender/nationality, if available) and their overall rating (or whatever rating available)

Basically, the relation between certain variables and their outcomes. But make sure you have a clear question before you start looking for answers.

Comment: "Big Data" is often collected without any thought as to the questions you might ask of it. This is in effect a little big data question.

Comment: @Spacedman, you're right. The difference is in the means of data collection, I suppose.